# zoom background image if background-size: cover on button click

Tags: jquery, css, zooming

I'm trying to make zoom effect on button click in this project: http://memory-alive.com.ua/

I need the folowing: when user clicks on the button the background map is zoomed, focusing on the country, animation durations is 2-3 sec. And after animation ends user is redirected to the /map page of the project.

I've tried to use jquery scale on BG, but since it is 100% of page width I get all site scaled, scrolls everywhere and everything seams broken.

I've also tried this aproach [background-transition with background-size: cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384684/background-transition-with-background-size-cover) but the author uses fixed width and height wrapper div which I can't use cause I need full width and height BG to scale.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: here: https://jsfiddle.net/nitoiti/0xvjhvLv/1/