# jQuery - background-size: cover + some percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to zoom background image smoothly when hovered, and to prevent making any empty space in div, I used `background-size: cover` attribute. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384684/background-transition-with-background-size-cover) thread says animation is not allowed in keyword values. So I'm going to use jQuery to implement the animation.

But I can't figure out what to set new `background-size` value in jQuery when hovered. I want to zoom 10% more, and `background-size: cover+10%` won't work of course. What should I provide to achieve what I want?

Here is my current code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #slide_sub {display: table; width: 100%}
    #slide_sub div.image {height: 300px; width: 50%; display: table-cell; background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; transition: 0.2s; vertical-align: middle; padding: 24px; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
    #slide_sub div.image:hover {background-size: cover 110%; transition: 0.2s}

    #slide_sub div.text {width: 100%}
</style>

<div class="image" style="background-image: url('a.png')">
    <div class="text">
        <p class="title">TITLE</p>
        <p class="subtitle">SUBTITLE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384684/background-transition-with-background-size-cover/27385703#27385703)

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Text in div should not be zoomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo element would be prefect for this, so you can keep the existing markup.

Combine it with `transform` and you get this

```css
div.image {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
div.image::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

div.image:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1.25);       /* 25% increase */
}
div.text {
  position: relative;           /* so text stay ontop of image */
}
```

```html
<div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1/)">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="title">TITLE</p>
    <p class="subtitle">SUBTITLE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color:#fff;
}

.bg_image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/500/500");
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.wrap:hover .bg_image {
  transform: scale(1.5)
}
```

```html
<div class=wrap>
  <div class="bg_image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="title">TITLE</p>
    <p class="subtitle">SUBTITLE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mouseenter and mouseleave method` here of `jQuery` to just `animate background` images as below,

> mouseenter() - Fires assigned styling, when mouseenter an element.
>   mouseleave() - Fires assigned styling, when mouseleave an element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
 $(".image").on("mouseenter",function(){
   $(this).css({
     "background-size" : "120% 120%",
      "transition" :"background-size 1s ease"
    });
  });
  $(".image").on("mouseleave",function(){
   $(this).css({
     "background-size" : "100% 100%",
      "transition" :"background-size 1s ease"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.image{
  background:url(" http://placehold.it/350x150") no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid #111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
    <div class="text">
        <p class="title">TITLE</p>
        <p class="subtitle">SUBTITLE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just figured out that `background-size: 100% 100%` works like `background-size: cover`. But anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: @AlfredWoo `background-size: 100% 100%` does **not** work like `background-size: cover` .... resize the above sample's width and you'll see it distort the image

Comment: @LGSon Ah well you were right.. I misunderstood. I think I have to apply another solution

Comment: @AlfredWoo Both mine and Abhishek Pandey solution does exactly what you look for

Comment: @LGSon I think so too though i couldn't tested.. but yours looks working like magic! I think i need to learn about pseudo code..!

Comment: @AlfredWoo Here I have used 100% 100% to scale it back to original size, by expanding it's width and height to 120%. cover won't work in above codes, instead it breaks that transition.

Comment: No problem @AlfredWoo Go with solution that you understood and worked for you. You added that you can't figure out using jQuery that's why I added this or CSS solution were good for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('.image').hover(function(){
   $(this).animate({height: '500px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
   $(this).animate({width: '500px', opacity: '0.8'}, "slow");
   });
});
```

I think animation can be applied like this. Hope this is what u asked.